# Speed loss when copying from Mac Book Pro to WD My Cloud over 802.11ac

Tags: macos, ethernet, macbook-pro-retina, 802.11ac

I am having difficulty diagnosing why my speeds are so much slower using 802.11ac  than gigabit Ethernet.  When using rsync, my measured speeds over wifi are ~12 MB/s.  Using rsync over gigabit ethernet, my speeds are ~25 MB/s, which is acceptable based on the speed of the hard drive. I have tested ethernet connections at the router and all switches with the same speed.

All wifi testing is done sitting next to the router.  Option-clicking wifi gives a connection speed of ~900 Mbps.  I have a different network SSID for 2.4 GHz and 5 GHz and I only connect to 5 GHz.  All channels have been checked for interference.  All file testing is done with the same, single large file for consistency.

Equipment list:

- MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Late 2013), El Capitan 10.11.5
- AirPort Time Capsule 802.11ac (Firmware 7.7.7)
- WD My Cloud (Firmware 04.04.03-113)
- All gigabit switches
- All Cat 5e or 6 ethernet cable

Comment: Sitting next to the router may actually make you too close, overloading the front end of the radio receivers and causing distortion that lowers your rate. RSSI above -40 dBm is too hot for many radios. Target something less than that, but still above -60. You should be able to get the 1300Mbps rate at 2-5 meters.

Comment: When you use the rsync tool, are you having it use the rsync protocol (does the WD My Cloud even support that?) or are you mounting the disk via SMB or AFP? What speed do you get when running iperf between the 802.11ac-connected rMBP and another gigabit ethernet-connected Mac on the LAN port of the Time Capsule?

Comment: I also have tried multiple other distances with the same results.  I only mentioned it so everyone knew I wasn't 100 feet away :-).  For the below results of iperf i am approximately 3 meters away from my router:

Comment: Wireless to wireless:
195 MBytes   163 Mbits/sec
Wireless to ethernet:
500 MBytes   419 Mbits/sec

Comment: Are there any other WiFi devices connected to your Airport? Slower devices can reduce WiFi speeds even if they are not transferring much data.

Comment: I change the SSID to disconnect all devices, then logged in with my MBP.  Speed did not change much.  I also tried writing to my Time Capsule hard drive and received the same results.  So now it looks like the issue is not with the WD, but with the Time Capsule.  Seems that I cannot transfer large files above 12 MB/s via wifi, even if my Tx Rate shows 867 Mbps (108 MB/s) when option-clicking the wifi.

Comment: It's likely that whatever remote filesystem protocol you're using (SMB or AFP) has latencies between read or write operations that cause it to not keep the TCP pipe full, and also don't allow 802.11ac to take full advantage of frame aggregation. I recommend you follow the directions you can find elsewhere online to enable the rsync daemon on the WD My Cloud and transfer files directly that way, without connecting to the drive first (i.e. rsync only, no SMB or AFP).

Comment: Thanks @Spiff.  I took your advice and successfully installed rsync.  I ran it with a direct IP address connection, no mapping, but I did not get an improvement.

Comment: @L.Frankel So are you using an "rsync://" URL or double colons "::" in your rsync command syntax? If not, you're still not using the rsync protocol.

Comment: rsync --progress /Users/XYZABC/Desktop/test.dmg  root@###.###.#.###:/shares/Public is the syntax that I'm using.

Comment: I also tried the following and got an error:
rsync /Users/XYZABC/Desktop/test.dmg  rsync://root@###.###.#.###/shares/Public

@ERROR: Unknown module 'shares'
rsync error: error starting client-server protocol (code 5) at /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync-47/rsync/main.c(1398) [sender=2.6.9]

Comment: UPDATE: I used the following after doing more research and got slightly improved results.  I'm up to about 15 MB/sec for a 4 GB image.  Below is what I used and the results:
rsync -avz --progress -h /Users/XYZABC/Desktop/test/ root@###.###.#.###:/shares/Public/test/
building file list ... 
3 files to consider
./
.DS_Store
       6.15K 100%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#1, to-check=1/3)
pi.img
       4.03G 100%   15.87MB/s    0:04:02 (xfer#2, to-check=0/3)

sent 1.07G bytes  received 70 bytes  4.31M bytes/sec
total size is 4.03G  speedup is 3.75